# MariaDB throwing syntax error when creating foreign key

Tags: foreign-keys, constraints, mariadb

I'm currently trying to learn a thing or two about databases, so i've been through W3Schools PHP and SQL course, and i've now set out to create my own little application, a forum, a simple one.

However, i've run into an issue with foreign keys. I've been through MariaDB's documentation on foreign keys and constraints, and i simply cant tell why i've got this error. The cause most likely is that i've stared too much at the code, and now i cant see my errors anymore.

So now i'm asking for help, when i'm running this piece of SQL on my XAMPP PHPMyAdmin, i'm getting the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''fk_topics_to_titles'
    FOREIGN KEY (titleID) REFERENCES titles(id)
' at line 8
```

Thats a syntax error right there, i've commented the area where the error occurs and my full script looks like this:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS eForum;

CREATE DATABASE eForum;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS eForum.titles(
    id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    titleName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    creator varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    createDate TIMESTAMP,
    lastUpdate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS eForum.topics(
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    topicName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    creator VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    createDate TIMESTAMP,
    lastUpdate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    titleID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, /*after this is where the error occurs*/
    CONSTRAINT 'fk_topics_to_titles'
        FOREIGN KEY (titleID) REFERENCES titles(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS eForum.threads(
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    threadName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    threadText TEXT NOT NULL,
    threadImage VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'sloth',
    creator VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    creatorCorp VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Pikachu',
    createDate TIMESTAMP,
    lastUpdate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    topicID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT 'fk_threads_to_topics'
        FOREIGN KEY (topicID) REFERENCES topics(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS eForum.posts(
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    postName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    postText TEXT NOT NULL,
    postCreator varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    postCorp varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'get in corp',
    createDate TIMESTAMP,
    lastUpdate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    threadID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT 'fk_posts_to_threads'
        FOREIGN KEY (threadID) REFERENCES threads(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I'm prety sure i've managed to copy the structure from the documentation here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/foreign-keys/ and as far as i know, it doesnt matter if i'm using tinyints, shortints or regular ints.

Please help me out here, i'm completely lost, i've been through all related questions to this post (which were suggested, and i cant seem to find anyone with a similar issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backtics, not quotes, around the `CONSTRAINT` name.

Comment: Pretty sure i already tried that, but for the sake of trying, i tried again. I'm still getting the same error, in the same place. :/

Comment: Works for me in 5.6.

Comment: I don't see any differences with MariaDB.

Comment: Oh wow, i'm dumb.

Appareantly i couldnt see the difference between ` and ' on my keyboard.

i either need a bigger screen or new glasses.

Thanks a bunch for the help!

The original error came because i saw the ticks as these: ' on mariadb's webbie.